# ImageIO inside jar file

Tags: java, image, jar, javax.imageio

Okay so I'm trying to make an API for my intro screen to be used across multiple games and I've spent the last 5-6 hours trying to figure out this 1 problem.

Lets say that I have the API.jar referenced in on of my games and I'm trying to call the method getByteArray() which is supposed to load the frame as a BufferedImage then return the byte[] data. I constantly get input == null when attempting to load the image.

```
public byte[] getByteArray() throws IOException {
    // Open Image
    String url = "/com/jumpbuttonstudio/api/resources/intro/Frame (" + current_frame + ").jpg";
    System.out.println("Loading: " + url);
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(url));

    DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer();

    return (data.getData());
}
```

I really need help with this, I can provide more information if required.

## NOTE

The code above is in the API.jar and so are all the images.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Class.getResourceAsStream(path)`, the path must start with a `/` (otherwise it's considered as a path relative to the class package). If you use `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(path)`, the path must NOT start with a `/`.

Comment: Testing this and I'll let you know about my results